# Jquery background color effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to create an efect that's change de background color from left to right.

I have created this: http://jsfiddle.net/kT95d/58/

```
    <style>
#div1{
height:200px;
width:200px;
background-color:green;
float:left;
}

#back {
width:0px;
height:200px;
background-color:Gray;
display: block;
}
```

```
<script>
    $('#div1').mouseover(function (){
    $('#back').animate({width: '200px'}, 1000);
});
</script>
<div id="div1">
<div id="back">
That was amazing!
</div>
</div>
```

But, i want the text in horizontal and how you can see, this is vertical and after the effect go to horizontal.
I don't know if this is the best way to do this. Can help me?
Thanks!!

Comment: You mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/kT95d/59/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go.  I believe this is what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/WVWKE/

Change is here:

```
<div id="div1">
    <div style="position:absolute">That was amazing!</div>
    <div id="back">
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem before was that the text was inside your zero width div, so it was breaking onto multiple lines to try to fit.  Then when you animated the width back to 200, the text had room to expand again.

Here we move the text out of the animated background div and into the parent div, then we give it a `position:absolute` to take it out of the flow so it doesn't take up space.  You can of course move that inline style to your CSS, and probably should.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
    #div1{
        margin-top: -200px;
        height:200px;
        width:200px;
        background-color:green;
    }

    #back {
        width:0px;
        height:200px;
        background-color:Gray;
        display: block;
    }
</style>
<script>
    $('#div1').mouseover(function (){
        $('#back').animate({width: '200px'}, 1000);
    });    
</script>
<div id="text">
    That was amazing!
</div>
<div id="div1">
    <div id="back">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```